# Android: Couldn't init Cursor Window

Tags: android, window, cursor

I'm getting the following error and stack traces:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't init cursor window
at android.database.CursorWindow.native_init(Native Method)
at android.database.CursorWindow.<init>(CursorWindow.java:41)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.fillWindow(SQLiteCursor.java:276)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.getCount(SQLiteCursor.java:268)
at android.database.AbstractCursor.moveToPosition(AbstractCursor.java:171)
at android.database.AbstractCursor.moveToFirst(AbstractCursor.java:248)
```

Does anyone know why?  I can't reproduce the error on my devices (works fine for me).

Comment: http://androidbridge.blogspot.in/2011/09/illegalstateexception-couldnt-init.html

Comment: On my application I have this error *ONLY* with CINK PEAX phones on 4.1.1. Do you have it with any kind of device or with only specific devices/android versions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think you should :

```
if (!cursor.isClosed() ||cursor != null)
             {
                     cursor.close();
                     cursor=null;
             }
```

and all you open cursor should close,and put close  at the last

Comment: I didn't do exactly what you wrote but I just ensured that all of my cursor code was executing correctly (e.g. I didn't try to close a cursor that wasn't open).