# Android java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't init cursor window

Tags: android, database, cursor, android-sqlite, illegalstateexception

I have this error on google play crash report and don't know how fix it :

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't init cursor window
at android.database.CursorWindow.native_init(Native Method)
at android.database.CursorWindow.<init>(CursorWindow.java:41)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.fillWindow(SQLiteCursor.java:276)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.getCount(SQLiteCursor.java:268)
at android.database.AbstractCursor.moveToPosition(AbstractCursor.java:171)
at android.database.AbstractCursor.moveToFirst(AbstractCursor.java:248)
at com.jim2.UpdateService.restaureNotifications(UpdateService.java:274)
at com.jim2.helpers.Globals.updateWidgets(Globals.java:1011)
at com.jim2.helpers.Globals.onReceive(Globals.java:746)
at com.jim2.UpdateService$5.onSignalStrengthsChanged(UpdateService.java:747)
at android.telephony.PhoneStateListener$2.handleMessage(PhoneStateListener.java:387)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3693)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:907)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:665)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Here is my code who have the crash :

```
    DataBaseHelper d = new DataBaseHelper(context);
    Cursor c = d.getNotifications(false);
    SharedPreferences preferences;
    String ns = Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE;

    NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager)context.getSystemService(ns);

    CharSequence tickerText = "";

    if(c!=null && c.moveToFirst()){ // CRASH HERE :(

        do{
                       ....
       while(c.moveToNext());
       if(c!=null && !c.isClosed()) {
                c.close();c = null;
       }
    }
    d.close();
```

Here the code to get the cursor from getNotifications :

```
public Cursor getNotifications(boolean all) {
        //removeAllNotifications();
        Cursor c;
        String fields[] = new String[] { "id", "ordre", "is_active"};
        String where = "is_active = 1";
        if(all)where = "";
        c = myDataBase.query(TABLE, fields, where, null, null, null, "ordre");

        return c;
    }
```

My problem is i can't reproduce the crash so it's hard to fix cause on my devices all works correctly.

Already see this post [Android: Couldn't init Cursor Window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9862696/android-couldnt-init-cursor-window) but me it crash on moveToFirst not later and i already add code in answer.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 5, accepted):

this exception is thrown by the native code. (refer to [this](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/3f2821425f1ab6eddb76a8725e3f2c3edb5d8b07/core/jni/android_database_CursorWindow.cpp))

mainly it is due to failing to allocate memory for the new cursor being created. so my guess is that the data you are fetching sometimes get too too much (nearly more than 1M in memory) or you are opening lots of cursor without closing them untill you ran out of memory to allocate a new buffer.

1. go through your code and insure you close all your cursors in a `finally` clause.
2. if the data being fetched from the database could go too large, get them in separate chunks (like doing a pull to fetch more in a list of something).

let me know if this helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this !!! I can't test cause i can't reproduce error but i check my code and forgot some close() so i think it's this (i hope). It can't be my data cause i have max 5 row and 3 fields ^^

Comment: Hi i have put update on google play and exception is still here :( i have search and now all my cursors are closed. Do you have another idea to fix this ?

Comment: i'm pretty sure the dangling unclosed cursors is the major and common cause of this error. each opened cursor allocates a 1M of memory until there is no space to do. please let some other guy (a different eye) to look at your code. and please let me know what you found.

Comment: Ok i will look again and try to show my code to another person to be sure. For now i have only one report with the last version so maybe it's non close cursor of the previous version who do this crash... it's possible ?

Comment: I have always the crash :( but i think it's a memory problem like you said. But this memory problem is no more cause by non closed cursor. I don't know how find where are memories problems :(

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, but shouldn't it be

```
        c = myDataBase.query(TABLE, fields, where, null, null, null, "ordre DESC")
```

Comment: No cause ordre is a field it's not ORDER and i want 0 to x so it's ASC (or nothing cause it's default)